Problem with apps script web app + materialize autocomplete on dynamic table
I have problem with forcing materialize autocomplete to work on dynamic table. It works fine on static element of the table. I am using js document.createElement. Console tells me html looks the same:
console.log(tbody) of dynamic element of table
...but like mentioned before, only static element of table shows autocomplete dropdown:
working static dropdown:
My code:
*****HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<?!= include("page-css"); ?>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="autosearch.js"></script>  
  </head>
  <body>

        <footer class="page-footer #2196f3 red"> 
           <div class="container">
              <table>
                 <tr>
                 <h3 style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Requested projects:</h3>

                 </tr>
              </table>
           </div>
        </footer>
  
  
<br>
<br>


<div class="container-fluid" style="width:100%; font-size:13px;  padding:0px; margin:0px;">
    
      <table border = "1" id="tableData" class = "#eeeeee grey lighten-3" style="width:90%; margin: 0px auto; align: center;">
        <thead>

          <tbody>
          <tr>
WORKING STATIC TEST OF AUTOCOMPLETE:
            <td>
              <th>
                      <div class="input-field">
                        <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
                        <label for="autocomplete-input"></label>
                      </div>
              </th>
            <td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>

          <tr>
              <th>Code</th>
              <th>name</th>
              <th>Please select project:</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="table-body">

        </tbody>
      </table>  
    

<?!= include("page-js"); ?>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

*****JS:
<script>

//EVENTS


  //ON LOAD EVENT
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  loadingData();
  }); //mozna tez DOMContentLoaded zamiast load


  //DROPDOWN EVENT
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  //  document.dispatchEvent(new Event('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete');
    var instances = M.Autocomplete.init(elems,{
      data:{
        'option 1':null,
        'option 2':null,
        'option 3':null
      }, minLength: 0
    });
  });




//FUNCTIONS

  function loadingData(){
   //just loading rotating thing
  }



  function generateTable(dataArray){
    console.log("generateTable")
    var tbody = document.getElementById("table-body")

    let numb = tbody.childNodes.length;

    for (a = 1; a<numb; a++){
      tbody.removeChild(tbody.firstElementChild);
    }

    dataArray.forEach(function(r){
      var row = document.createElement("tr");

      var col1 = document.createElement("td");
      col1.textContent = r[0];
      row.appendChild(col1);

      var col2 = document.createElement("td");
      col2.textContent = r[1];
      row.appendChild(col2);

      var col3 = document.createElement("td");
      
//not working dynamic autocomplete
      var th = document.createElement("th");
      col3.appendChild(th);
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.setAttribute("class", "input-field");
      th.appendChild(div);
      var input = document.createElement("input");
      input.setAttribute("type", "text");
      input.setAttribute("id", "autocomplete-input");
      input.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete");
      div.appendChild(input);
      var label = document.createElement("label");
      label.setAttribute("for", "autocomplete-input");
      input.appendChild(label);

      
      row.appendChild(col3);

      tbody.appendChild(row);

      console.log(tbody)
      const old_tbody = document.getElementById("table-body")


    });   
   
  }

</script>

For sure this is some stupid mistake (propably with event) but I am quite new to web apps and have no clue what am I doing wrong.
I would like dynamic element of table (materialize autocomplete dropdown) to works just like that test static element.

This is because the only place you initialize the materialize autocomplete is within the eventlistener for DOMContentLoaded. This is why the static content works but the dynamic content does not.
Does it make sense to reorganize the initialization into its own function that you can call for DOMContentLoaded but can also call as needed after dynamic content is added?
